# Css star Tim Vasil

Tags: css, firefox

I put on my site using css (Tim Vasil) for the stars in reviews.
But I realized after putting the site online, which in firefox css does not work well
why?

[script css Tim Vasil](http://www.timvasil.com/blog14/post/2013/03/16/Seeing-stars-star-rating-CSS.aspx)

This is the CSS:

```
i.star {
background-image: url(../img/star-sprite.png);
display: inline-block;
height: 16px;
width: 80px;
background-position-x: -80px;
background-position-y: -48px;
}

i.star-1    { background-position-x: -64px; }
i.star-2    { background-position-x: -48px; }
i.star-3    { background-position-x: -32px; }
i.star-4    { background-position-x: -16px; }
i.star-5    { background-position-x: 0; }
i.star-qtr  { background-position-y: -32px; }
i.star-half { background-position-y: -16px; }
i.star-3qtr { background-position-y: 0; }
```

chrome on the stars work depending on the class called,
on firefox I always all yellow stars

Comment: Please show your code so we can see what you've done.  Providing the code in jsfiddle (or equivalent) as well is helpful.  We can't help if we don't know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Also have no idea what you are asking?

Comment: chrome on the stars work depending on the class called,
on firefox I always all yellow stars

Comment: Read this, then please edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox does not support `background-position-x` or `background-position-y`. Try this instead:

`i.star { background-position: -80px -48px; }`

`i.star-1 { background-position: -64px -48px; }`